# jQuery validate working, but allows form submission with invalid data

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I've been poring over this for hours, and at my wits' end. I have two forms on the same page, both of which using jQuery validation to confirm valid data prior to submission.

#### EDIT:

Including the code below.

#### Two things:

1. For some reason, the first form (registration form) is being validated, AS I am entering data. So it appears it's firing on keyup/blur events, but is NOT firing properly when I click the submit button. As you can plainly see, it allows the form to be submitted with empty OR invalid data.
2. The login form on the right. It works! but I need to click the submit button **twice** for it to actually submit the form.

Fist-full of hair over here. Please, anyone able to assist on this one?

#### EDIT:

Adding the code here, as requested. First, the registration validator:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    
 $.validator.addMethod("PASSWORD",function(value,element){
        return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{5,}$/i.test(value);
        },"Your password must be at least 5 characters long. Please include 1 or more numbers.");
  $.validator.addMethod("lettersnumbers", function(value,element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
        }, "Username can only contain letters and numbers. No spaces are allowed.");    
 $.validator.addMethod("BIRTH",function(value,element){
        var age = 18;
                
        switch($('#Province option:selected').val())
        {
            case "NB":
            case "BC":
            case "NL":
            case "NS":
            case "NY":
            case "YT":
            case "NU":
            case "AL":
            case "DE":
            case "NE":
            case "NV":
            case "OH":
            case "TN":
            case "UT":
            case "VA":
            case "WI":
                age = 19;
                break;
            case "MS":
                age = 21;
                break;      
                            
        }
        if (new Date().getFullYear() - year <= age)
        {                                   
            return false;           
        }
        return true;
        },"In order to be eligible to Register, you must have reached the age of majority in your Province, Territory, or County of residence.");
 var validator = $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            Captcha: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "/js/validate_captcha.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        action: function () {
                            return "checkcaptcha";
                        },
                        username: function() {
                            var Captcha = $("#Captcha").val();
                            return Captcha;
                        }
                    }
                }               
            },          
            Password: "required PASSWORD",
            PasswordConfirm: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#Password"
            },
            Username: {
                required: true,
                lettersnumbers: true,
                maxlength: 18,
                remote: {
                    url: "/js/validate_username.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        action: function () {
                            return "checkusername";
                        },
                        username: function() {
                            var Username = $("#Username").val();
                            return Username;
                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            Country: "required",
            FirstName: "required",
            LastName: "required",
            Email: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "/js/validate_email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        action: function () {
                            return "checkemail";
                        },
                        username: function() {
                            var Email = $("#Email").val();
                            return Email;
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: true
            },
            EmailConfirm: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                equalTo: "#Email"
            },
            BirthDate: { 
                required: true,
                BIRTH: true
            },
            Agreement: "required",
            AgeCheck: "required",

        },
        messages: {
            captcha: "CAPTCHA response is required" ,
            Agreement: "You must agree by checking the box" ,
            AgeCheck: "You must agree by checking the box"  ,       
            EmailConfirm: "Email Addresses do not Match",
            lettersnumbers: "Username can only contain letters and numbers. No spaces allowed.",
            noSpace: "Username cannot have spaces",
            PasswordConfirm: "Please re-enter the same password as above",  
            Username:{
                remote: "This username is already taken. Try another.",
                maxlength: "Username may not be longer than 18 characters."
            },
            Captcha:{
                remote: "You have entered an incorrect CAPTCHA response."
            },              
            Email:{
                remote: "This e-mail is already taken. Try another."
            },          
            Password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long. Please include 1 or more numbers."            },
            required: "Required Field" ,
        },
    }); 

});

</script>
```

Now, the login validator:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 
   var loginvalidator = $("#form_login").validate({
      rules: {
          LoginUser: {
              required: true,
              remote: {
                  url: "/js/validate_login_username.php",
                  type: "post",
                  data: {
                      action: function () {
                          return "checkusername";
                      },
                      username: function() {
                          var Email = $("#LoginUser").val();
                          return Email;
                      }
                  }
              }             
          },    
        
          LoginPassword: "required"
        
      },
      messages: {               
          LoginUser: {
              required: "Required Field",
              remote: "The username or email entered was not found. Please note, your username must contain only letters and numbers, and never any spaces. Try logging in with your email address instead." },
          LoginPassword: {
              required: "Required Field",
              remote: "Password is incorrect. Please try again." },
      },
   });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question so it can be read by others in future facing the same problem.

Comment: Webpage Not Available :/

Comment: Try to keep it short and simple.

Comment: Sorry--link is working now.

Comment: I will include the code in the question as well...

Comment: @Ajinkya: Not sure how the above question is anything but short and simple?

Comment: @FurryWombat: (Your question before edit) `Just search the HTML for .validate.` IMO Instead of asking others to find problem area you should pinpoint it.

Comment: @Ajinkya: Quite sure I pinpointed the error in my question. Validation is working, but something else appears to be bound to the submit event, or the validator is not preventing submission by default as it should. It's validating data as it is entered, but allows invalid form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Answer below has been edited based on comments]*

As nothing particularly wrong jumps out from the code:

- try enabling the debug option {debug:true} in each validator in order to get some output to the console to spot problems.
- you are not being explicit about which events you want to validate on, consider adding {onkeydown:false, onfocusout:false, onclick:false} to the options hash in order to limit valiadation to on-submit events only.
- there are also some unneccessary trailing commas in your rules hashes after closingbrackets. perhaaps not enough to cause an error but I am always tempted to clean out thing like that when I am getting unexpected behaviours. [Note: @Sparky, this is only an issue in older versions of IE.]

PS: Original Poster solved the issue which was due to failure of BIRTH function due to the use of a hidden field which was silently being being populated by invalid data by the browser (firefox) and causing validation to fail.

Comment: Was able to track it down to the BIRTH method, which was not working properly because I had a hidden field defined as a display:none text field, and Firefox was auto-populating the field with an innocuous string. Changed to a hidden field, and works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Bullet point #2, `onsubmit: true` is the default behavior.  You are not supposed to use `true`; just use `false` to disable it, or leave it out entirely otherwise.  Bullet point #3, "Trailing Comma of Death" is only an issue in older versions of IE.

Comment: @FurryWombat, then why did you "accept" an answer that has absolutely nothing to do with your actual solution?  This helps no-one looking to SO for answers to their own problems.  The best thing would be to post your own answer and accept that instead.

Comment: @Sparky: Because Steve was the only one who didn't spend their time making useless remarks and ignoring the question because the link I originally provided was dead for (gasp) a whole thirty seconds. Steve actually provided solid advice--if not quite as specific as one might like. His answer led me to debug the issue a different way, via debug:true, which led to the answer, which I provided detail for, above. Rather than answering my own question, which would have been an all-but-smooth move, kudos to Steve for actually attempting to help. Thank you, Steve.

Comment: @FurryWombat, you may be grateful that Steve made an attempt to help you, but accepting any answer, let alone a poor one, simply out of appreciation is very detrimental to the SO community. Writing your own answer in this case is infinitely more helpful to everyone.

Comment: @Sparky: You're right. Well, now that the question has been closed, I do not have the ability to answer it myself. SO etiquette, lesson learned. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for the kudos @FurryWombat. :) as I'm the only one able to edit the answer I've attempted to make it more useful, as suggested.

Comment: @stevejpurves: Rock star!